# Derivative of logarithm function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

differentiate -

$y = x ( \ln x)^2 $

I simplified it to -

$y = x ( 2\ln x) $

My workings -

$y' = x \frac{d}{dx} (2\ln x) + 2\ln x \frac{d}{dx} (x) $

$y' = x \frac{2}{x} + 2 \ln x (1) = 2 + 2\ln x $

Where did I go wrong ? The answer I should get is

$ ( \ln x)(2+ \ln x) $

Comment: $(\ln x)^2 \neq 2\ln x$ whereas $\ln (x^2) = 2\ln x$

Comment: Indeed, $y\ne 2x\ln x$.

Comment: http://www.derivative-calculator.net/#expr=x%28lnx%29%5E2&showsteps=1

Answer (score 0):

$(ln(x))^2 ≠ 2*(ln(x))$

$(ln(x^2)) = 2*(ln(x))$

Answer (score 0):

Given
$$
  y(x) = x \ln^{2} x
$$
compute $y'(x)$.

---

Use the *product rule* for derivatives.

$$
\begin{array}
%
 y'(x) &= x \left(\frac{d}{dx} \ln^{2} x\right) + 
\left( \frac{d}{dx} x \right) \ln^{2}x \\[3pt]
% 
 &= x \left( 2 \ln x \frac{1}{x} \right) + \ln^{2} x \\[3pt]
%
 &= 2 \ln x + \ln^{2} x
%
\end{array}
$$

This reduces to 
$$
 y(x) = \left( 2 + \ln x\right)\ln x 
$$

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused by the logarithmic identity

$$\log(x^2) = 2\log(x)$$

Generally,

$$(\log x)^2 = (\log x)(\log x)\neq 2 \log(x)$$